# azure entity framework: new table is not created, internal server error when trying to insert data

Tags: azure

i am stuck here for days now:

all i want is to create a table called useritems and upload data into it, this is my middleware:

```
    [Route("tables/useritem")]
    public class tblUserController : TableController<UserItem>
    {
        public tblUserController(AppDbContext context)
            : base(new EntityTableRepository<UserItem>(context))
        {
            
        }
    }
}

public class UserItem : EntityTableData
{
    [Required, MinLength(1)]
    public string Email { get; set; } = "";
    public string Telephone { get; set; } = "";
    public string Password { get; set; } = "";
}
```

app context:

```
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {

        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The dataset for the UserItems.
        /// </summary>
        public DbSet<UserItem> UserItems => Set<UserItem>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Do any database initialization required.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A task that completes when the database is initialized</returns>
        public async Task InitializeDatabaseAsync()
        {
            await this.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("C5"); // set the connection string name that you set up (caused issues before) 

if (connectionString == null)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("DefaultConnection is not set");
}

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatasyncControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

// Initialize the database
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
    await context.InitializeDatabaseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

// Configure and run the web service.
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

as far as my understanding goes, this should create a table. and once I try to insert data into it, it should show up in my SSMS. but it doesnt.

When I open the link to the db I get this:

[image]

So it seems to have been created and running.

Funniest part:

If I create a table via SSMS and the create table command that is of the name UserItems and has all the features of the entity table, I CAN create data from my app but not READ it. So the auto create fails and therefore the connection must have an issue.

Why arent my tables created automatically?